# Laravel session database duplicate key error index

Tags: laravel-4

I am getting this error and any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am using mongo db as my default session database. Laravel seems to try to insert session data in table every page visit with the same session Id which generates duplicate index error.
I created my sessions table using:

```
php artisan session:table
composer dump-autoload
php artisan migrate
```

and then I set the correct properties in the app/config/sessions.php.
The first session value gets inserted correctly in the table but there is an error of duplicate index error on page refresh or redirect.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by executing bd.sessions.drop() on the database.

https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/78

The problem resolved immediately.